# Find roots of the equation $y=2 \sin(3x+40), \;x \in (-2\pi, 2\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, roots

Find the roots of the equation:

$$y=2 \sin(3x+40), \;\;x \in (-2\pi, 2\pi)$$

In the book given that there are 12 roots exist.  I am able get only 2 roots. Could anyone explain?

Comment: How did you obtain the roots? Remember that
$$
\sin{x} = \sin{y} \Leftrightarrow x = y +n2\pi \text{ or } x = \pi -y + n2 \pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

Comment: Because of the multiplier $3$, the argument of the sine crosses $6$ periods. As the sine has $2$ roots per period, you have it.

Comment: thanks @ Yves Daoust

Comment: Is the $40$ $$40^{\circ}$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y = 2\sin(3x+40)$$

Set $y = 0$.
$$0 = 2\sin(3x+40) \implies \sin(3x+40) = 0 \implies 3x+40 = \sin^{-1}0$$

From here, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$: $$\sin^{-1}0 = 0+2\pi n \text{ OR } \sin^{-1}0 = \pi+2\pi n \\
\implies\sin^{-1}0 = \pi n$$

Solve the equation now.
$$3x+40 = \pi n \implies 3x = \pi n-40 \implies \boxed{x = \frac{\pi n-40}{3} = n\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{40}{3}}$$
From here, we can find the number of roots for the restricting domain of $x \in (-2\pi, 2\pi)$.
$$-2\pi < \frac{\pi n-40}{3} < 2\pi$$
$$-6\pi < -\pi n-40 < 6\pi$$
$$-6\pi+40< -\pi n < 6\pi+40$$
$$\frac{-6\pi+40}{-\pi}> n > \frac{6\pi+40}{-\pi}$$
$$6-{\frac{40}{\pi}} > n > -6-\frac{40}{\pi}$$

Subtract the maximum and minimum values.
$$6-\frac{40}{\pi}-\biggr(-6-\frac{40}{\pi}\biggr) = 12$$
So, there are $12$ roots. As a matter of fact, the answer would remain $12$ regardless of the value of $h$ in $y = 2\sin(3x-h)$.

Another way of thinking about it would be to consider the periodic nature of sine. For $y = a\sin[b(x-h)]+k$, the length of a period is given by  $\frac{2\pi}{b}$.

$$\frac{2\pi}{b} = \frac{2\pi}{3}$$

For $x \in (-2\pi, 2\pi)$, the number of cycles/periods can be found by
$$\frac{4\pi}{\frac{2\pi}{3}} = 6$$
Each period has $2$ roots, so there’ll be $12$ roots for the given function.

Comment: Neat answer, KM101!  The way I had solved the equation, I clean forgot $\sin \theta$ has two solutions - $0$ and $\pi n$.